# SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php, mysql

Создаю веб-приложение по типу "Моего календаря"

На финальном этапе возникает ошибка

Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /home/konfosipov.hostfl.ru/public_html/calendar/foo.php:45 Stack trace: #0 /home/konfosipov.hostfl.ru/public_html/calendar/foo.php(45): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/konfosipov.hostfl.ru/public_html/calendar/foo.php on line 45

Строки в которых по идее должна быть ошибка, и скриншот базы данных прилагается

````
$name = $_POST['name'] ?? 'Добавить тему';
$type = $_POST['task_type'] ?? null;
$location = $_POST['place'] ?? null;
$description = $_POST['description'] ?? null;
$duration = $_POST['duration'] ?? null;
$date = $_POST['date'] ?? null;
$time = $_POST['time'] ?? null;


if (!empty($_POST)){
    if (isset($_POST['add'])){
        $sql = ("Insert into tasks(`name`,`type`,`location`,`description`,`duration`,`date`) values(:name,:type,:location,:description,:duration,:date)");
    }elseif(isset($_POST['update'])) {
        $sql = ("Update  tasks set `name`=:name,`type`=:type,`location`=:location,`description`=:description,`duration`=:duration,`date`=:date where id=$task_id");
    }
    $query = $tasks_object->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute([
        ':name' => $name,
        ':type' => $type,
        ':location' => $location,
        ':description' => $description,
        ':duration' => $duration,
        ':date' => $date. ' ' .$time,
    ]); ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGKUo.jpg
````

Comment: А чего task_id напрямую в запрос шлëте? Кстати, где он берётся?

Comment: `<?php
include './db.php';
$task_type = ['meeting' => 'Встреча','case' => 'Дело','call' => 'Звонок'];
$status = $_GET['status'] ?? 0;
//read
$sql = 'Select * from tasks';
$tasks = $tasks_object->query($sql);
$tasks->execute();
$tasks = $tasks->fetchAll();
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $task_id = $_GET['id'];
    foreach($tasks as $value){
        if($value['id'] == $task_id) $task = $value;
    }
}
`
Данная часть кода писалась другим человеком, поэтому сам не могу понять